# React-Native arrays comparison

Tags: listview, react-native, arraylist, lodash

I'm trying to compare two arrays and then display the result in a listview, both arrays are retrieved from firebase, I do know how to retrieve the data(arrays) from firebase however I do not know whats is the best way to compare them.
I expect the listview component displays the result once a data from array1 is matched with array2.
Anyone knows how to do it?
thanks in advance,

[image: data retrieved from firebase]

Comment: When you say compare, what are you looking for? The difference between the arrays? The intersection?

Comment: The arrays contain a list of codes, I'd like to be notice, if any code from array1 appears in the array2 and then display the corresponding code in a listview

Comment: i have attached a picture of my lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution: use nested loops.

```
let identicalElements = [];

array1.forEach((element1) => {
  array2.forEach((element2) => {
    if (element1['code'] === element2['code'])
      identicalElements.push(element1['code']);
  });
});

console.log(identicalElements);
```

There might be plenty of faster solutions but for use-cases where there aren't a lot of array items, I guess this gives a decent ROI.

Comment: instead of running the console.log(), i need to save/keep the element in a list, I tried to do e.g return {  ...element2.code }
but I got an error.. any idea how to do it?

Comment: Updated the answer. At the end of the loop, array `identicalElements` would have all the codes that are found in both original arrays.